# String to DateTime conversion in PowerShell

Tags: string, datetime, powershell

I am trying to convert the time stamp value of a file to date time for comparing two date time differences.

The data would be coming in format **24122014_022257**. I need to convert this into date time so that I can compare the values:

```
$usdate="24122014_022257"   
$dateParts = $usdate -split "_"   
$final = $dateparts[0] + $dateParts[1]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the ParseExact method:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('24122014_022257','ddMMyyyy_HHmmss',$null)

Wednesday, December 24, 2014 2:22:57 AM
```

Comment: Use `[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` rather than `$null`. The latter will raise an error if for instance the format string has an AM/PM designator while your system's regional settings don't.

Comment: I usually just add the 'tt' specifier to the format string if I'm converting a data that uses AM/PM specifiers.

Comment: I don't see the point in adding an option to handle cultural differences in AM/PM designators doing a ParseExact on strings that don't have that designator.

Comment: On my system ` [datetime]::ParseExact('24/12/2014','dd/MM/yyyy',$null)` raises an exception but `[datetime]::ParseExact('24/12/2014','dd/MM/yyyy',[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)` works fine.

Comment: @miracle173 That's weird; `[DateTime]::ParseExact('24/12/2014','dd/MM/yyyy',$null)` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 10):

ParseExact will do just that. You can specify custom datetime format in second parameter. You can leave third parameter as null, or specify a culture to use (it may matter if you're importing files that were generated from system with different time zone).

```
$usdate="24122014_022257"
[datetime]::ParseExact($usdate,"ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)
```

Answer (score 5):

get-date 24122014022257

Wednesday, December 24, 2014 2:22:57 AM

Comment: For me this returns: 
28 January 0001 22:03:21