# Cannot convert this string to Date object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been struggling with this for some time now and I've tried everything I could find but, have yet to be successful. I need to convert this string to a Powershell date object:

20180802 16:30:10

Everytime I try ParseExact, it's saying that it doesn't recognize the string as a valid date/time format.

Comment: Please show us the actual code (including the format string and the full error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to DateTime conversion in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741810/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-powershell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following works perfectly:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('20180802 16:30:10', 'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

I bet your problem is 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

[Pawel Dyl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824468/45375) is the correct and robust solution.

Just to offer a shortcut that may be of interest in similar situations where only a *simple textual reformatting* is needed in order for a `[datetime]` *cast* to recognize a string containing a date/time representation:

Transforming `20180802 16:30:10` to `2018-08-02 16:30:10` would work:

```
PS> [datetime] ('20180802 16:30:10' -replace '^(\d{4})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-')

Thursday, August 2, 2018 4:30:10 PM  # sample output on a US-English system
```

Note that a `[datetime]` cast in PowerShell uses the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture), as PowerShell does in [many contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).