# How can I set a Azure DevOps Pipeline Varible which contains the date in this Format: 25.07.2020

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-server-2019

I'm not using yaml, because my company uses TFVC, so I need the classic way.

With $[pipeline.startTime] I get the starttime, but now I need it formated in this way: dd.MM.yyyy

A powershellscript like in [VSO(TFS) - get current date time as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738944/vsotfs-get-current-date-time-as-variable) helped me, but set the day directly in the variables would be a cleaner way

Comment: Are you trying to set the date on a pipeline variable and you are saying what you are setting is in the format you provided?    Have you looked at this already?  Using ParseExact.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741810/string-to-datetime-conversion-in-powershell

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom TFS Enviroment Variable doesn't read $(Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094110/custom-tfs-enviroment-variable-doesnt-read-date)

Answer (score 11):

> How can i set a Azure DevOps Pipeline Varible which contains the date in this Format: 25.07.2020

Since you are using the classic way, **nested variables** are not supported in the build pipeline. So, we could not use the variables like `$(Get-Date -Format Date:MMddyy)` to set the date time.

We could only set the variable like:

```
$[format('{0:ddMMyyyy}', pipeline.startTime)]
```

In this way, we could get the value `10072020`, not the `10.07.2020` without `.`. And I could not add any interval between `ddMMyyyy`, it does not supported by Azure pipeline.

Besides, as workaround, we could defined the Build number format in the **Options** tab with value `$(DayOfMonth).$(Month).$(Year:yyyy)`:

[image]

Then we could use variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)` directly to get the date time:

[image]

Comment: $currentDataTime = $(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss) how to convert this format of date in Azure Pipeline from UTC to add 10 hrs?

Comment: For those who ask how to reproduce a month number with two digits, here is mine:
`$(Year:yyyy).$(Date:MM).$(Date:dd)$(rev:.rrr)`. I use $(Date) instead of $(Month).

Comment: `> And I could not add any interval between ddMMyyyy, it does not supported by Azure pipeline.`  
Actually it's supported, just escape them with backslash, e. g. `$[format('{0:yyyy\-MM\-dd\THH\.mm\.ss}', pipeline.startTime)]`

Answer (score 5):

You can define a Azure DevOps Pipeline Variable by using expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops
It supports .NET custom date and time format specifiers:

```
$[format('{0:dd}.{0:MM}.{0:yyyy}', pipeline.startTime)]
```

Answer (score 0):

[@ChamindaC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48106324/109941) inspired my solution:

```
Write-Host "Setting up the date time for build variable"
$myDate=$(Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd-Hmmss)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyDate]$myDate"
```

And then later in my pipeline I can refer to `$(MyDate)`.

[image]

---

For your specific date format, you could do this:

```
Write-Host "Setting up the date time for build variable"
$myDate=$(Get-Date -format dd.MM.yyyy)
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyDate]$myDate"
```